# Submitting a form in ColdFusion that has special characters

Tags: html, coldfusion, lucee

I have a form that contains textboxes and textareas with user entered data. I am using a simple ColdFusion actionpage with a cfquery tag to submit the data to my database.

```
<cfquery name="add_ticket" datasource="#datasource#">
INSERT INTO service_ticket(end_user, customer_id, ticket_id, company_name, service_description, service_date, status, customer_signature, technician_signature, materials, ticket_type, equipment, discount, percent_discount, material_subtotal, material_tax, material_shipping, material_total, billable_service_total, tax_rate, grand_total, equipment_id, equipment_name)
VALUES("", '#get_customer.customer_id#', "#ticketnum#", "#url.customer_name#", "#url.description# - #get_equipment.equipment_name#", #CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#, "In-progress", "0", "0", "0", "#url.TT#", "0",  '0.00', '0', '0.00', '6.625', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '#subscriber.tax_rate#', '0.00', "#get_equipment.id#", "#get_equipment.equipment_name#")    
</cfquery>
```

I sporadically run into errors submitting this query because the values for certain columns contain special characters.

For instance, the value for company_name might be: Smith & Johnson, LLC.

The ColdFusion code breaks once it hits the ampersand. I've tried enclosing the value in single quotes and double quotes as well as

```
<cfqueryparam value="#url.company_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" />
```

but nothing seems to help.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

I'm currently running a Lucee server.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you use the query parameter?

Comment: So I have a button that calls the action page:

window.open(href='actionpages/add_ticket_maintenance.cfm?TT=commercial&equipment_id=#id#&customer_name=#customer_name#&description=Equipment Maintenance&end_user=Scheduled maintenance', "_self");

When that calls the actions page the customer_name URL variable cuts off once it hits the & symbol. So the ColdFusion error that is given is: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'customer_id' at row 1  . This is because it has only received half the URL variable it is expecting.

Comment: To avoid OTHER more serious problems like sql injection, you should really, really, really update all of your queries to use cfqueryparam with the matching cfsqltype (not just varchar for everything) (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comment I now understand what the issue is.  The solution to your problem is to use the ColdFusion function [`encodeForURL()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforurl.html) when calling your action page using javascript.

Change your code from

```js
window.open(href='actionpages/add_ticket_maintenance.cfm?TT=commercial&equipment_id=#id#&customer_name=#customer_name#&description=Equipment Maintenance&end_user=Scheduled maintenance', "_self");
```

to

```js
window.open(href='actionpages/add_ticket_maintenance.cfm?TT=commercial&equipment_id=#id#&customer_name=#encodeForURL(customer_name)#&description=Equipment Maintenance&end_user=Scheduled maintenance', "_self");
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked!

Comment: That's great @BrianFleishman.  Since the actual code in question was in the comment section of your question, would you please update your question with the code from your comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have options.

You can change your form to something like this:

```
<form action = actionpages/add_ticket_maintenance.cfm
target = "_blank"
method = "post">
```

This will submit the form to a separate window or tab.  On your action page you will have to use the `form` scope instead of the `url` scope.

Or, you can encode your url variables with the [EncodeForUrl](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforurl.html) function.  Your choice.